# Laravel 5 - Can not migrate

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I am working with Laravel 5.2. I want to add some tables to my database, so I've created a new migration file and tried to run the migration.

When trying to run `php artisan migrate` I get the following error

```
[PDOException]                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

But the password is correct. I can access my DB via Sequel Pro (OS X) and the website itself is working, too (I can create new users etc).

I work with homestead, but changed the default database. I've restarted the VM and tried `php artisan config:clear`.

My .env:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:SDXEyixnQr+qVCH8hbY2bRo3yQtmL8BwEbwY94tDPRc=
APP_URL=http://palabi.dev

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=palabi
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=password

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

And my Homestead configuration

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Homesteadprojects/sites
      to: /home/vagrant/sites

sites:
    - map: test.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/test
    - map: laravel-53.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/laravel-53/public  
    - map: palabi.app
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/palabi/public

databases:
    - homestead
    - palabi
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the problem.

Laravel tried to connect to my local database (where no user `homestead` exists). But it must connect to the database from the Homestead virtual machine.

In my .env I had to change `127.0.0.1` to the IP from my Homestead configuration file `192.168.10.10`.